# Fast way to save images from 3 different webcams

Tags: performance, delphi, webcam

I have 3 webcams and I would like to store all the frames on my HDD in Delphi. I have done this, but the problem is that it's quite slow. I was thinking about storing the data into a big file like an iso I tried, with BlockWrite and it is about two times slower than saving them with a different name in a folder as bitmaps.

Edit: I attached a a new screenshot, where you can see it's performances. In this test, it had only one hd webcam with 15 frames/sec and saving the frames as JPG(using Delphi XE2 native JPEG library) in the a HDD folder.I was able to see that the software actually store only 2 I/O output Mega byte of data each second on my HDD from only one high resolution 3D camera. But in one minute the software loose 70-80 frames. 
[image]

Any suggestions, solutions? Thanks

Comment: Did you try putting each camera into its own thread?

Comment: @JerryDodge That presupposes that the program is CPU bound. More likely to be disk bound. Multiple threads likely to make it slower!

Comment: @user558126 Can you tell us where the bottleneck is? Before anyone can give sound advice we need to understand the problem.

Comment: Each camera gives me 30 frames per second. I managed to write a simple code that is able to save the frames as BMP or JPG in the HDD but over time it is lagging and loose frames.

Comment: @User558126 Open your task manager, do a run and keep an eye on your disk light. You should be able to see whether the CPU is pegged at 100% or your disk light is burning continuously.

Comment: I will try this, and I will come with performance status. But what if I write the entire all in a BIG file instead of thousands of pictures? Wouldn't it be faster?

Comment: Step 1, work out what the bottleneck is. Step 2, devise solution. You keep asking about step 2 without performing step 1.

Comment: I edited the original post with more details, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to write video you can use component TAVIRecorder of GLScene.
I wrote four HD(1280*720)*25fps video from IP cams and have good result with it and x264 codec and less than 40% of processor using  i7 4770
So, after writing complete you can play it with any videoplayer and get nedded picture

Comment: Can I use TAVIRecorder also to display current frame from the webcam?

Comment: No, you can't display video only for write.

Comment: Do you know any other Webcam Video recorder solution that is able to save very fast all frames and also to have the oportunity to display them ? What about VideoLAB form Miltov?

Comment: May be DSPack can help you. I never used VideoLAB and can't say to you anything about it.